# How can I add the Memtest86+ options back to the Grub menu?

Tags: grub2, memtest

[**If using UEFI Please see this question, *"Can I boot memtest86+ if I'm using UEFI?"***](https://askubuntu.com/q/917961/29097)

After having installed the 64bit version of Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo B570 I ran into the same problems I had when installing 11.10 with Grub not playing nicely with a uEFI system. I used the same technique as last time to solve the problem (using a Super Grub Disc LiveCD session to repair Grub) and my system happily dual boots between Ubuntu and Windows 7

However now when I boot up the Grub menu only displays

- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic
- Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-24-generic (recovery mode)
- Previous Linux versions
- Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
- Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda4)

I no longer see the option to use Memtest86+ which was there previously, having checked in the Ubuntu Software Center I can see that the package is installed, but how to I make the option to run it once again appear in the Grub menu?

I've tried:

```
sudo update-grub
```

which doesn't make any difference.

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
```

results in:

`chmod: cannot access /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+': No such file or directory`

and entering

```
ls /etc/grub.d/
```

results in:

```
00_header        10_linux      30_os-prober  41_custom
05_debian_theme  20_linux_xen  40_custom     README
```

Comment: Try adding the script as detailed below, copied it from my machine, do the chmod +x and grub update and see if that works. I see you did - welcome.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try opening a terminal and running

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
sudo update-grub
```

Check to see if it's there

```
grep memtest /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Just done the same as I had it disabled

```
$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep memtest

$ sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
[sudo] password for hob: 

$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Ubuntu 11.10 (11.10) on /dev/sda6
Found Trisquel 5.5 (5.5) on /dev/sda8
Found Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sda9
done

$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep memtest
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
```

You could try creating the file if it's not there, using nano in a terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
```

or with a gui editor

```
gksudo gedit /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+
```

Fill it with

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ -f /usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib ]; then
  . /usr/lib/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib
  LX=linux16
elif [ -f /usr/lib/grub/update-grub_lib ]; then
  . /usr/lib/grub/update-grub_lib
  LX=linux
else
  # no grub file, so we notify and exit gracefully
  echo "Cannot find grub config file, exiting." >&2
  exit 0
fi

# We can't cope with loop-mounted devices here.
case ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} in
  /dev/loop/*|/dev/loop[0-9]) exit 0 ;;
esac

prepare_boot_cache="$(prepare_grub_to_access_device ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} | sed -e "s/^/\t/")"

if test -e /boot/memtest86+.bin ; then
  MEMTESTPATH=$( make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "/boot/memtest86+.bin" )
  echo "Found memtest86+ image: $MEMTESTPATH" >&2
  cat << EOF
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
EOF
  printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}"
  cat << EOF
  $LX   $MEMTESTPATH
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
EOF
  printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}"
  cat << EOF
  $LX   $MEMTESTPATH console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
EOF
fi

#if test -e /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin ; then
#  MEMTESTPATH=$( make_system_path_relative_to_its_root "/boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin" )
#  echo "Found memtest86+ multiboot image: $MEMTESTPATH" >&2
#  cat << EOF
#menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, experimental multiboot)" {
#EOF
#  printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}"
#  cat << EOF
#   multiboot   $MEMTESTPATH
#}
#menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200, experimental multiboot)" {
#EOF
#  printf '%s\n' "${prepare_boot_cache}"
#  cat << EOF
#   multiboot   $MEMTESTPATH console=ttyS0,115200n8
#}
#EOF
#fi
```

Make sure to run the `chmod +x` command on it afterwards.

I'd be a bit concerned that it's missing though - do you have everything else in grub.d ?

```
$ ls /etc/grub.d/


00_header        10_linux.bak       20_memtest86+  41_custom
05_debian_theme  10_linux.dpkg-old  30_os-prober   README
10_linux         20_linux_xen       40_custom
```

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+` resulted in: `chmod: cannot access /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+': No such file or directory`

Comment: Edited answer to include this

Comment: Added ls /etc/grub.d/ result to question, no mention of memtest, but your answer has now made it work perfectly, thank you.

Comment: I found `20_memtest86+` lurking in `/etc/grub.d.bak/` somehow. Moved it into place, updated GRUB and everything worked fine for me.

Comment: `update-grub` doesn't find memtest binary no matter what I do :(

Comment: That file is present and filled with those contents and with those permissions, I added semicolons so you know when the lines of the output end:   aaronfranke@aaron-xubuntu:/etc/grub.d$ sudo update-grub;
Generating grub configuration file ...;
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic;
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic;
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic;
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic;
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi;
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration;
done;

Comment: what could be the reason if the file is present but still the option does not come out to the grub menu?

Comment: isn't this because the GPL versions of memtest don't support EFI? So if you are booting through EFI, there is _no way_ to get memtest to work using what's shipped with Ubuntu??

Comment: I got the following, X@ubuntu:~$  cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep memtest
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

Comment: I tried this and after choosing memtest86+ I got blank page, but if I click "enter" or "f1" it makes the bip as it running ,do you any suggestions ?

Comment: @JeffAtwood POKE

Comment: when I typed ```sudo nano /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+``` it opens up the file with everything already in it. But the chmod command doesn't recognise the file nor can I search with grep. I have Ubuntu dual booted with windows.

Comment: Linux can do memtest https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439769/105120

Answer (score 23):

```
apt install memtest86+
```

This will automatically reconfigure grub and add the entry to the boot menu.

If you get the error `memtest86+ is already the newest version` then use
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall memtest86+`

If all else fails you can get a [bootable ISO](https://www.memtest.org/) that you can burn to a CD and boot from. Of course if you are booting UEFI you should be [here instead.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/917961/can-i-boot-memtest86-if-im-using-uefi)

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 server this was exactly the solution. Without `apt-get install memtest86+` mentioned file `/etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+` was not present on my system.

Comment: @mstrap, it was the solution for me too. I don't understand why my answer was downvoted two times.

Comment: This solution did not work for me - the above command received a `memtest86+ is already the newest version` message. I suspect this solution only works for non UEFI systems while the original question is specifically regarding memtest on UEFI systems.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, like JayDin memtest was already installed.
I used synaptik package manager to remove memtest, rebooted then re-installed it. This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Does this work on a live USB?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, and due to the fact that I have EFI on my laptop the memtest86+ version 4.x shipped by ubuntu won't work, since EFI is only supported by version 5 and newer.

The latest versions are non-GPL and must be downloaded manually from the memtest website(they have ISO and USB images), but at least they are free of charge.

Comment: http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

Comment: The latest versions are non-GPL and must be downloaded manually from the memtest website(they have ISO and USB images), but at least they are free of charge.


     memtest86 is non-GPL and proprietary and memtest86+ is GPL.

Answer (score 6):

I didn't managed to make this work in 2 days, then I checked Synaptic for grub packages...
Seems to be, that the absence of package `grub-imageboot` are the root of the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install grub-imageboot
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Found memdisk: /boot/memdisk
Imagepath /boot/images not found

Answer (score 3):

This what I did to add the now latest (non-free) memtest86+ to the grub boot menu for UEFI booting. Current memtest version is 8.2.

**Tools needed**: Disk Image Mounter and grub-customizer, the latter is only for convenience :)

**Files**: memtest binary (see below).

1. Download the memtest binary from: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm
   The 'Image for creating bootable USB Drive on a Windows/Linux/Mac system' is fine.
2. Extract the IMG file (memtest86-usb.img)
3. Open the img file with disk image mounter (right mouse button on Ubuntu)
4. From the mounted image extract /EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
5. Make memtest86 boot directory:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /boot/efi/EFI/memtest86
   ```
6. Copy the BOOTX64.efi to your new folder on the boot partition (eg /boot/efi/EFI/memtest86)
7. Open grub-customizer
8. Add menu item, give it a name, choose type: other
9. Add the following boot sequence (assuming you boot from **hd0**):

   ```sh
   insmod part_gpt
   insmod fat
   set root='hd0,gpt2'
   if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  1A22-970F
   else
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 1A22-970F
   fi
   chainloader /EFI/memtest86/BOOTX64.efi
   ```
10. Save and quit grub-customizer
11. `reboot` and enjoy Memtest86

Comment: For others/me: #3 Disk Image Mounter = gnome-disks. #6 must be root. #8 Why is type other not memtest? #9 how do you know if you boot from hd0? [click edit on your boot drive entry and copy the entry for that setroot]. Thanks for this excellent answer btw.

Comment: If one's ubuntu root is hd2 then presumably you change the 0 to 2 in 4 places, inc ahci? Regardless I get error no such device 1A22-970F & file '/EFI/memtest86/BOOTX64.efi' not found. File is defo in /boot/efi/EFI/memtest86/ . Any thoughts? Cheers

Comment: 'error disk hd2,gpt2 not found' now appears with 'no such device'; file not found doesn't appear. not sure why it would change...

Comment: This may help others having issues mounting the EFI partition of the img file: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1576011.html

Comment: memtest86+ (https://www.memtest.org/) is free and GPL ! 
memtest86 (no plus sign here) (https://www.memtest86.com/) is not. I just sorted out that confusion for myself.

Comment: Use "sudo blkid" to get the correct EFI partition UUID. For me the EFI partition was on /dev/sdb3 so root='hd1,gpt3' and ahci0 is replaced by ahci1

Answer (score 1):

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439769/64687) on the Unix StackExchange. In short, the Linux Kernel has a simple memory test built in.

Do `grep CONFIG_MEMTEST "/boot/config-$(uname -r)"` to determine if it's enabled or not (it'll be commented out if it's not enabled).

Then, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `memtest` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, run `sudo update-grub`, and then reboot.

Once it's finished booting up (it'll take longer than normal given it has to also run the memory test), check `/var/log/kern.log` for the result of the test.