# Mouse and keyboard not working after 10 minutes

Tags: keyboard, mouse

my laptop for a whole week has gone crazy, what I mean?

Well... when I open it, all works good, the mouse and the keyboard, but, after 10 minutes, all stops working, and I can't move the mouse or write anything.

Does anybody know what is the problem, please...?

Thank you!

Comment: can you give me an example of some script?

Comment: no, I don't have any of those scripts...

Comment: fine . when you boot your system ,open system monitor to see is there any process which start consuming a lot of cpu. However I am deleting my previous comments.

Comment: I'm sorry if i've got you mad, I just answered your answer.. I will do it and see.

Comment: No. Actually I deleted those because it was useless.

Comment: As @Guru, I guess it must be a process which is using a lot of CPU. Maybe keyboard and mouse become unresponsive also because of the high CPU temp

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down and restarting the laptop.

[Check the logs for errors.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186276/where-are-all-the-major-log-files-located)

[Run a memory test.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502) If you can't find the memtest86+ option on the menu see [this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu)

Check [smart status of drives.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077)

In case of overheating, blow out the vents and consider installing [TLP.](https://askubuntu.com/a/564080/225694)

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth playing with power manager settings. Just trying this on my clean install of 20.04. Thought it was specific to wireless keyboard and mouse but borrowing a wired one same thing. In my case mouse pointer still moves but buttons don't respond. Will report back shortly.
Happens even if no programs running.

Will report back in half an hour or so.
Edit: so far no joy with power manager settings but found this https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/how-to-move-a-mouse-pointer-automatically-in-linux-to-simulate-user-activity/ and that has solved the problem for me.

Comment: No joy yet, will try some more changes.