# Overheating and battery draining

Tags: lenovo, 14.10, battery, overheating

About a month ago, I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on Lenovo T430 removing the current OS Windows 7. First two - three weeks everything was working smoothly. After then, my laptop started to overheat and battery life started to drain quicker. It fell down from 2.5 hours to approximately 1 hour. Although I have been using it for more than a month I am still new to Ubuntu. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: overheating could also be the hardware. Battery life depend on how you used it and taking care of it. Not always Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For all supported versions of Ubuntu**

You can install [TLP](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tlp&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), a power management tool, to improve the battery life and reduce overheating.

> TLP brings you the benefits of advanced power management for Linux
> without the need to understand every technical detail. TLP comes with
> a default configuration already optimized for battery life, so you may
> just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to
> fulfil your specific requirements.
> You can obtain TLP in one of 2 ways.

Since Wily, TLP is available by [enabling the Universe Repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and issuing the commands `sudo apt-get update` to update the package list
And to install tlp and it's recommended packages

```
sudo apt install tlp tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

If you wish to install from the [PPA.](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

Open a terminal an enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tlp
```