# Failed install of ubuntu 16.04 & 15.10 with error message "following file did not match its source copy..."

Tags: system-installation, io

I am helping my son run Ubuntu on an old Dell desktop (Inspiron 580; 3G86G : Module,Processor,I3-550,3.2,4, Clarkdale,580/S; J510R : Module,Hard Drive,1TB,7.2K PHAR-XLOB P325K : Module,Dual In-Line Memory Mod ule,6GB,3X2GB,1333,INSPDT) so that he can play Minecraft, of course!

Until a week ago, we had Windows 10 & Ubuntu 15.10 happily dual booting. My son (then I) stupidly chose to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 using the LiveUpdate. It went pear-shaped! I will not describe my ordeals but I will jump to my final predicament. I have downloaded an iso installation file of Ubuntu 16.04 and have repeatedly attempted to install with the option of "erase disc & install Ubuntu 16.04" (having long given up hope of getting to the Windows partition which we hardly ever used). Everything goes well until just after the screen where you define your username & password. Ubuntu begins installing then stalls at the same point (about 20-30% into the installation) with the error message "The following file did not match its source code on the CD/DVD /target/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQt5WebKit.so.5.5.1" If I try to skip this error, I hit a final screen saying an I/O error has occurred and offers to send a report. On repeated attempts, the crash occurs at the same point & the same file.

The help text in the Ubuntu installation suggests a faulty DVD among other explanations. I see the same explanation on various forums. This disc checks fine, was validated when written, & I have successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 on another laptop using the DVD. So it's fine in my book!

In exasperation, I thought that there might be a conflict with the Dell hardware. Ubuntu 15.10 loaded perfectly 4 months ago. So I tried going back to re-install Ubuntu 15.10 (using the erase disc/install fresh Ubuntu 15.10 option). Everything goes well until the corresponding spot in the Ubuntu 15.10 installation, which stalls with the same error message ""The following file did not match its source code on the CD/DVD ...similar but not exact same file name". You can imagine the expletives that I voiced!

I am totally bemused! My simpleton's view is that two installation DVDs for different versions of Ubuntu can't have the same error so the discs are OK. I am doing a fresh installation of Ubuntu so there can't be anything on the hard drive. I am just about to fiddle with the RAM in case a faulty RAM may produce these I/O mismatches.

I am left with a machine that will only boot from the DVD. The file system is not recognised by my Windows 10 installation disc. So the machine is a "doorstop" and my son is "climbing the wall" unable to play Minecraft.

Comment: Possible reasons: 1) Faulty image file---> check `md5sum` and verify.  2) Faulty CD/DVD player, ---> try booting from a USB 3) Bad burning of CD/DVD ---> try creating a bootable CD/DVD at lower than 4x speed. (slower is better when t comes to bootable!)

Comment: Test your RAM with memtest86+ for at least one night. Any LiveDVD you've made will work. Here is how to run it: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502

Comment: It might be a problem with the DVD reader (since also the Windows installation disk is faulty). I strongly suggest to you that you move to using USB sticks for installations.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your assistance. It was a faulty RAM problem. I had installed a 4GB RAM chip to upgrade to the maximum 8GB compatible with this Dell model. When I replaced the "new" 4GB chip with the original 2GB chip, everything worked! I presume that the Ubuntu installs "filled" memory to the faulty RAM segment (which was repeatedly at the same spot) and crashed.

Thanks again!