# Ubuntu crashes - where can I look for the cause?

Tags: crash

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 a few days ago after receiving my laptop from a major hardware repair. Unfortunately, it crashes often (a few times daily), and I cannot discern a pattern as to what might be the cause. The first few times it was when running `unison` and synchronizing files, but last time it crashed when it was streaming music and not being 'actively used'.

Raising the pink elephant (alt+sysreq+ R, E, I, S, U, B) does not help and also not cause the system to reboot.

The crashes usually cause visual artefacts on the screen; see screenshot: [image]

Does someone know, where I could look to find the cause?

I've looked in /var/log/syslog, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: I would begin by checking RAM as outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502 and follow up by checking the SMART status of the drive(s) in use as outlined here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Here are the results: Smart status is OK. Memtest took me a while - it's not present in grub due to EFI, I had to make a bootable usb for memtest 4 - and it runs for about an hour without errors before the screen mysteriously turns black and the keyboard backlight starts blinking... Running it for a second time now.

Comment: Using memtest 7 (for EFI) I found many errors in RAM. Many thanks for the help! Off it goes, straight back to where it came from: Lenovo repair service. I can't help but wonder what it is they do in that place.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out. I converted the comment to an answer in the hopes that others with the same issue will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule out drive issues by check Smart status of the drive(s) as outlined on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04)

Run memtest86 to rule out memory errors as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502). If you have an EFI system you'll want V5 or later which support EFI boot. The latest version is available [here](http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)