# VirtualBox 5.1.0 Disable auto - pause

Tags: virtualbox

My guest is a vm ubuntu 16.04 on Virtualbox with host windows.
Once I start vm, it goes to pause automatically several times.
Without changing the amount of memory for guest, is there a way to disable auto-pause ? (This state is a warning from VB to let me know windows might experience lack of memory)
Kian William

Comment: I assigned like 1024 M to guest, for host I used readyboost to make up the amount of ram I assigned to guest. Amount in readyboost is around 4096 MB and the ram to my laptop is 2 GB.  If readyboost is considered a different type of ram, the answer to your question is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Using different RAM types, memory caching applications or other host techniques that affect access to physical RAM may affect RAM allocation of the guest in VirtualBox.

If we can't avoid such techniques in the host we may try to [enable pre-allocation of RAM](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=73800) for a virtual machine with the following command:

```
VBoxManage setextradata <vmname> VBoxInternal/RamPreAlloc 1
```

---

Another cause for issue with RAM allocation may come from guests that had [memory ballooning](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idm2314) enabled.

Comment: I did the command above, the host window went nut, quite frozen and vm did not start at all in such a way that I did a cold boot for host.

Comment: Also, to disable RamPreAlloc , assigning 0 to it is enough? I mean in the body of the same command.

Comment: A crash on starting a VM set to pre-allocate its RAM further indicates there is a hardwar issue with your RAM. Check for RAM errors with [memtest](http://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86).

Comment: I can not call it a crash, I assigned all ram to vm according to the RamPreAlloc 1, it is quite natural when I try to use a host program , it does not respond. Regarding vm, I was not exact, it started , but it loaded about  29 percent and very slowly, may be if I waited more, it would run. Any way, I returned back RamPreAlloc to 0 via vboxmanage command again, is it enough or there are other things I got to do?

Comment: @KianWilliamNowrouzian: you may also want to assign an execution cap to your CPU in case you use all cores for your VM.

Answer (score 0):

I notice this situation on my CentOS VS while I have another Ubuntu VS opened for weeks.
When I close that Ubuntu, CentOS stop auto pause.
So I think it maybe the memory issue.