# Hawaii (r9 390 with 4gb memory) shows only 3072mb. why?

Tags: drivers, video, ram, gpu-driver

i'm on ubuntu 16.04 with radeon r9 390 3x with 4gb of memory. 
Ubuntu sees only 3072mb. why?
thanks

update:

i'm using ubuntu for mining using claymore software. 
and claymore was saying that i have 3gb instead of 4gb and it wasnt running.

Comment: run memtest - https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502 you running 32 bit ?

Comment: 64 bit. memory is ok. checked for errors

Comment: run `sudo lshw -C memory`, `dmesg`, `journalctl -b`, and reboot into `memtest86+`

Comment: How did you test for errors ? I would open the case and test one stick at a time see if one if faulty or mislabeled.

Comment: Video Memory Stress Test 1.7.116

Comment: i found the problem. 
issue was app specific. 
i used export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=0
and it worked well

Answer (score 1):

i found solution for my problem using set values in script before running the application:

this is the solution 1 instead of 0

```
export GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR=1


export GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE=100
export GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS=1
export GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
export GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT=100
./ethdcrminer64 -epool eth-asia1.nanopool.org:9999 -ewal ....
```