# Ubuntu 14.04 Name mangling

Tags: filesystem, nfs, file-sharing

I don't know whats happening here, if I cp -Rfv /a /b the file names in the destination are suddenly getting mangled to 8.3 is gibberish characters.  This only started after I installed NFS and I do have old dos clients accessing it, but I don't understand why cp is mangling names that already comply to 8.3 even and not in exported directories. Copy single files seems to work more reliably.

On further investigation this appears to be a DOS client issue.  Only files in lowercase on the server appear correctly to the client, regardless of 8.3 qualifications. No idea how you fix that, I can't find anything substantive on NFS filename mangling.

TIA,
A

Comment: Examples? How are `/a` and `/b` mounted? Unclear what you're asking. 14.04 is EOL.

Comment: /a and /b aren't mounted they're regular directories, a filename might start as somefilename.txt and it comes out as STKSKVO.~F0

Comment: actually some of this got an upgrade, maybe that's change some default behaviour somewhere. To make things more complicated, I have NFS exports to DOS clients, and SMB for Win Clients.

Comment: @waltinator 14.04 is supported until [April 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Have you ruled out the possibility of [RAM faults](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86) and [Storage Device Failure](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek)

Comment: At this point yes storage devices are solid... RAM have to admit not tested but have no reason to suspect it.