# Where can I get the right driver for this old hardware in Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: drivers, graphics

I am really trying to install Ubuntu in my desktop, the problem: I has very old technology.

My motherboard is an: ASRock - N68C-GS4 FX.

8GB of RAM

AMD Radeon HD 5800 video card.

I am pretty sure I have enough power to use Ubuntu, but the drivers are so old they are not included in Ubuntu 18.4

I really want to use it, so **Where can I get the right drivers for my PC?**

This is what I got with sudo lshw -short:

```
H/W path              Device      Class       Description
=========================================================
                                  system      To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Fill
/0                                bus         N68C-GS4 FX
/0/0                              memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/3                              processor   AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor
/0/3/5                            memory      288KiB L1 cache
/0/3/6                            memory      6MiB L2 cache
/0/3/7                            memory      8MiB L3 cache
/0/4                              memory      8GiB System Memory
/0/4/0                            memory      8GiB DIMM Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.
/0/4/1                            memory      [empty]
/0/7                              memory      RAM memory
/0/1                              bridge      MCP61 LPC Bridge
/0/1.1                            bus         MCP61 SMBus
/0/1.2                            memory      RAM memory
/0/2                              bus         MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller
/0/2/1                usb2        bus         OHCI PCI host controller
/0/2.1                            bus         MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller
/0/2.1/1              usb1        bus         EHCI Host Controller
/0/2.1/1/2            scsi6       storage     USB DISK
/0/2.1/1/2/0.0.0      /dev/sdb    disk        16GB USB DISK
/0/2.1/1/2/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdb    disk        16GB 
/0/2.1/1/2/0.0.0/0/1  /dev/sdb1   volume      14GiB Windows FAT volume
/0/100                            bridge      MCP61 PCI bridge
/0/5                              multimedia  MCP61 High Definition Audio
/0/6                              storage     MCP61 IDE
/0/8                              storage     MCP61 SATA Controller
/0/8.1                            storage     MCP61 SATA Controller
/0/9                              bridge      MCP61 PCI Express bridge
/0/9/0                            display     Cypress XT [Radeon HD 5870]
/0/9/0.1                          multimedia  Cypress HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5830
/0/b                              bridge      MCP61 PCI Express bridge
/0/101                            bridge      MCP61 PCI Express bridge
/0/101/0              enp1s0      network     QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
/0/102                            bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 0
/0/103                            bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 1
/0/104                            bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 2
/0/105                            bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 3
/0/106                            bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 4
/0/107                            bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 5
/0/a                  scsi0       storage     
/0/a/0.0.0            /dev/sda    disk        250GB SAMSUNG HD250HJ
/0/a/0.0.0/1          /dev/sda1   volume      350MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/a/0.0.0/2          /dev/sda2   volume      183GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/a/0.0.0/3          /dev/sda3   volume      450MiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/a/0.0.0/4          /dev/sda4   volume      48GiB Extended partition
/0/a/0.0.0/4/5        /dev/sda5   volume      48GiB EXT4 volume
/0/c                  scsi4       storage     
/0/c/0.1.0            /dev/cdrom  disk        DVDRAM GSA-H10N
```

**I think I should have no problems with AMD drivers... but still, in the install it just crashes when downloading them. And without them, the installation does not work correctly**

Any help is much, much appreciated.

Comment: Which drivers in particular are you missing? Can you [edit] your question and include output of `sudo lshw -short`? Generally modules are not removed from the kernel because they are old, unless they belong to an arch that is no longer maintained, or has other problems

Comment: @vidarlo the thing is I don't know!
My install crashed as downloading the drivers I believe... Now I am about to install Ubuntu all over again!

Comment: When did it crash? What did you do before it crashed? What was showing on screen? I've had Linux running on *ancient* hardware, without problems. That includes computers made before the Linux kernel...

Comment: HI! Thanks!
The story is long, but you can check it out here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112533/problems-installing-ubuntu-18-4
(i included the sudo lshw -short output)

Comment: That story looks more like a hardware problem than missing drivers. Bad RAM may for instance lead to random crashes like what you expirience.

Comment: Mmmm... how should I test the RAM?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86 - it can be other things than RAM, but I would look to hardware before blaming missing drivers.

Comment: Let it run for at least two-three passes... That easily takes a few hours

Comment: @vidarlo could not do it. I ran into an old fashioned unetbootin screen similar to the one shown at the end of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ta3bw1CORj0
(sorry I could not find a better image)
I ran test memory and it said: cannot load a ramdisk with an old kernel image or something like that