# Ubuntu keeps randomly shutting down

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, power-management, shutdown, laptop

I have Ubuntu on my laptop and it keeps crashing out of no where.  I couldn't find anything in the syslogs or kern.logs about it at the times when it happened.  I don't know if it could be my battery since I don't know how to test it.  I think it might be because the crash it an instant shutdown, as if it was never powered on.

The laptop does has an NVidia card in it and I tried rolling back the drivers like in another post on here, but that didn't work.

I kept checking sensors between crashes (it happens multiple times within minutes of each other for a bit) but temps never got above 45C.

Is there another place in /var/log to look or some kind of tool to scan for error in the disk?  This problem has been happening for a while and I can't find anyone having the same problem.

Amy suggestions or more info I can give?

Comment: I purged the nvidia drivers completely and it hasn't happened in a couple days.  If it does I will update this; if not, that was the problem

Comment: Depending on the laptop it COULD be a problem with the design of the laptop.  Example: the system sensors reported 75C on my system, but the MOSFETs on the system board which 'regulate' temperature overheat too quickly due to some cooling issues in the Dell XPS 9570.  I had to make some after-market modifications to the system (basically, underclock the CPU, and turn the aluminum bottom of the laptop's chassis into a heatsink with thermal padding that goes from the mosfets to the chassis base to wick away heat so the system doesn't shut down due to that issue) to fix it in my case...

Comment: ... but as was said in answers, "Hardware Problems" usually suggest an instant power-off, maybe the nVidia drivers were overusing the card with everything, causing it to heat up and the system to trigger a thermal overheat power-off (which can sometimes happen)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is not in the OS but on hardware level. I recommend making a thorough check with memtest. Check this out for more info regarding memtest: [How do I run memtest86+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/)