# Ubuntu freezes on dual RAM sticks

Tags: 18.04, gnome, 19.04, freeze, ram

I had previously installed 18.04 and was using a single 8GB RAM. Later I upgraded to 16GB of RAM(2x8) and a 250GB SSD. I have made a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 but after using it for a few days it started freezing randomly. I searched a lot for the issues and figured out it could be because of some GNOME issues. I installed Unity desktop on 18.04 it was running smoothly then. Now I have upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 and the problem is still happening. It's freezing every now and then. But the interesting thing is it works completely fine with both the RAMs when I'm using then individually. 
Please help me with this I want to use both the RAMs and also want to use GNOME desktop.

Comment: Have you run memtest?  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MemoryTest)

Comment: @guiverc surprisingly my memtest86+ isn't working. whenever I'm pressing enter on memtest from the grub menu there is just a blank screen and nothing happens.

Comment: I would read that as a bad sign (ie. more weight on bad memory being your issue), however I'd just boot a 'live' (install-media) and use a memory tester that way.  If they too fail, try them on another box - if the work there, you've got your answer in my opinion (*bad memory*)

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed you to [How do I run memtest86+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86) because it's not reasonable for Linux to fail in this way. An operating system, be it Linux, MacOS, or Windows, will read and write memory in much the same way. However, it's possible for one operating system or program to appear functional on defective memory because they load different things into different memory regions.

In basic terms memory addresses 0 - 10 might work fine, but 11-20 might not, because of a hardware defect. This error could be with your memory sticks, motherboard, or the CPU itself - all of which have different roles in memory and bus management.