# I can't use all of my ram in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: ram

I noticed that my desktop wasn't running very fast so I checked how much RAM I had installed. I counted *12GB*. But when I looked at how much Ubuntu said I had, it only said *5.8GB*. Please help, 5 gigs is horrible.

Comment: How much memory have you got **as reported by the BIOS**?

Comment: might be off-topic, but 5GB should be plenty for normal usage (web, hd video, programming) without any slowdown on Linux. I get by mostly fine with 2GB :)

Comment: Try [running memtest86+](https://askubuntu.com/a/591502/965801).

Comment: system performance or speed DOESN'T depend upon amount of ram ,UNLESS it is not sufficient for the tasks.
ram is used to allocate memory for the ongoing process so that it can be readily accessed by processor. even if your ram is 16gb or 128gb ,if process only requires 1gb it only uses 1gb you should upgrade ram only when memory usage is more than 70% for normal tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you upgraded your RAM yourself at some point? Are your RAM components of different size? Your motherboard may require that the larger RAM has to go in the first slot, and the smaller RAM has to go in the second slot.