# NVME error 20.04 only reinstall helps

Tags: 20.04, nvme

I have a very big issue with Ubuntu. I have 20.04 installed on an M2 NVME Kingston SA2000 with ASRock b550 Steel Series. Sometimes it happens that Ubuntu crashes. I can open terminal and type a command, but any instruction does not finish.

Chrome is not responding. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> does not solve it. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+  <kbd>R E I U S B</kbd>  does not reboot the system - I get messages about the NVME error (device not ready).

Only hard reset helps, but then the system does never get alive. After hard resetting and mounting in safe mode, I get to `initramfs` with the message that the root filesystem on `nvme0n1o5` requires a manual check.

I have completely cleaned the NVME and installed Ubuntu again, losing all progress. But I keep getting errors again and again (once a week).

What may I try so I don't have to reinstall the whole system every week?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo or if you actually have you used it this way, but it's `Alt`+`PrtSc`+`R E I S U B` instead of `Alt`+`PrtSc`+`R E I U S B`.

Comment: You were supposed to run the `fsck` disk utility (while booted from a live USB device in "Try Ubuntu" mode) to find and fix errors on the disk. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hardware defect, most likely either your RAM or your SSD.

First check your RAM with memtest86:
[How do I run memtest86+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86)

Then use the Smartmontools to check your disk(s) / SSD: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools