# How can I start the Ubuntu "System Testing" to test my graphics card and graphics memory from the terminal or from a menu in Gnome Metacity?

Tags: gnome, graphics

How can I start the built in Ubuntu "System Testing" to test my graphics card and graphics memory from the terminal or from a menu in Gnome Metacity?

I'm having occasional system lockups, and suspect a graphics problem, or perhaps mouse problem.

Answer (score 1):

- The command for the one on the live session is [checkbox_ng](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/checkbox_ng.1.html).
- The most comprehensive one is the Phoronix suite ([download](https://phoronix-test-suite.com/releases/repo/pts.debian/files/phoronix-test-suite_10.8.0_all.deb) the DEB and open it with software center.

> I'm having occasional system lockups

System testing would not help you with that. Lockups tend to be memory issues. Run memtest for that (see [How do I run memtest86+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86) )

Comment: I can find no reference to `phoronix-test-suite` in the official repos.

Comment: @OrganicMarble AFAIK `phoronix-test-suite` is for benchmarking computer performance. I don't know if it can be used for testing RAM.

Comment: It will show details on hardware. It does not test ram indeed but technically that was not the question... but likely what should have been the question ;)

Comment: So how do I check / test graphics card memory ?