# Errors on my huawei matebok x pro 2020

Tags: 22.04, freeze, systemd, huawei, gnome-session

I am having problems with my Huawei matebook x pro version 2020 device using Ubuntu 22.04.
Since I installed it, my screen has frozen several times, I get a white Windows BSOD style saying "Something has gone wrong", constantly being in browsers like Firefox or Chrome, the browser closes without I touch nothing...

The errors that I get in the errors are the following in case you can help me:

```
13:51:24 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

13:51:22 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

13:51:22 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

13:51:22 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

13:51:20 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

13:51:20 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.

13:51:19 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

13:51:12 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

13:51:10 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)

13:51:10 thermald: Unsupported conditions are present

13:51:09 systemd: Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.

13:51:08 kernel:

13:51:07 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230331/psparse-529)

13:51:07 kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus is busy, can't use it!
```

I've had this laptop for 4 years and this didn't happen to me before and now it does.

Comment: You RAM may be failing. Please test it with https://askubuntu.com/q/591488/1004020 , and you can exclude the bad parts later. Otherwise, please look for more logs around the time of the problem from `dmesg` and `journalctl`