# How to add memtest86 entry to grub2 menu?

Tags: grub2, uefi

I want to test new memory, but can't find memtest86 entry in grub2 menu. I looked at script `/etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+` and found this lines

```
# We need 16-bit boot, which isn't available on EFI.
if [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

The directory `/sys/firmware/efi` exists. Why memtest menu entry not added, if `/sys/firmware/efi` exists?

Comment: I saw that question.  But there is no mention about /sys/firmware/efi.

Comment: It's not 100% clear whether the user in the [How can I add the Memtest86+ options back to the Grub menu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu) question is actually booting in EFI mode, but you definitely are, and some of the answers to that question directly address this condition.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to comment this lines and run `update-grub`

Comment: Menu entries are now shown, but nothing happens when I choose it.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did not read carefully. Found the answer in that question.