# Wireless not working in 16.04 Xenial - Intel chipset + Lenovo G50-70

Tags: wireless, 16.04, lenovo, intel-wireless

Tried all possible solutions I could find on the forum.

Here's the result of the wireless-info script.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 02 Sep 2016 08:05 IST +0530

Booted last: 02 Sep 2016 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, persistent, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [17aa:380a]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b4] (rev 93)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8270]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                311296  0
mac80211              737280  1 iwlmvm
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_soc_core          212992  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_pcm               106496  7 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwlmvm
ideapad_laptop         24576  0
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop
wmi                    20480  1 ideapad_laptop
video                  40960  2 i915,ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6ceb:aa68:e778:b4b3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8570 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7425521 (7.4 MB)  TX bytes:1107555 (1.1 MB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp1s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      2654     1  0 07:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d7a381bd-d70c-47f6-9993-0fc864355266
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{26}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d7a381bd-d70c-47f6-9993-0fc864355266 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.2/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             60.60.60.1
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        domain_name_servers = 60.60.60.1 8.8.8.8
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       expiry = 1472790245
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 7200
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.2
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       broadcast_address = 255.255.255.255
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       interface_mtu = 576
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       dhcp_option_overload = 3
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::6ceb:aa68:e778:b4b3/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceGeneric
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 3160 (Dual Band Wireless AC 3160)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-36-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               16.242414.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              yes
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0    no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     49DC02934CB3D8C312FF8E1
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     B10AF1CD828D26173EA0378
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode
srcversion:     651BF6CBF283F6F817B8F3A
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     25A45701AAA64DAC1E47D9D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.464276] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[   14.464349] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled (repeated 2 times)
[   14.607130] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   14.676605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   28.990665] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   29.130884] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link down (repeated 2 times)
[   29.130945] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0: link is not ready
[   30.712324] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: link up
[   30.712333] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp1s0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Other problems I am/was facing after upgrade to Xenial from Trusty till now (in case others are facing the same as well) :
1. Software & Updates UI doesn't open at all. Additional Drivers doesn't open (I have an AMD Radeon Graphics card)
2. CUPS service was eating up all the disk space [FIXED]
3. Software updater UI goes blank after clicking on Update

Comment: Any errors from `sudo ifconfig wlp2s0 up`

Comment: It sounds like a lot of stuff got corrupted. Can you try reinstalling `iwlwifi`?

Comment: @Zacharee1 - How do I do that correctly?

Comment: @Jeremy31 : No errors. But nothing happens

Comment: @Vandesh Try `sudo apt-get purge iwlwifi` and then `sudo apt-get install iwlwifi`.

Comment: That's what I tried. But it says, `unable to locate package iwlwifi`

Comment: That's quite a laundry list of problems.

Comment: This question appears to be too broad at first glance. Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I can only conceive of 3 ways all these errors could have a common source:

1) Corrupted ISO used for installation: See [MD5 hash for ubuntu .iso (14.04 through 16.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso)

2) Faulty RAM - See [How can I add the Memtest86+ options back to the Grub menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu) and [How do I run memtest86+?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86/591502)

3) Failing hard drive - See [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-16-04/528077)

If you performed the upgrade in place rather than from an installation ISO  the first one doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: If the root cause isn't one of these then your question will likely be closed as too broad and should be seperated into it's component parts so that we can efficiently help others who may have one (but not all) of your issues.

Comment: 1 is not applicable. Checked 2 and 3, but that doesn't seem to be a problem. Can you explain why these could be related to the Wireless not detected problem in the first place? Maybe I can dig further with that information

Comment: Also, I am not looking for help with the other problems, but only the Wireless one. The others I just mentioned, since someone else could be having a series of similar problems.