# Black screen instead of grub and then login screen GUI

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have an strange behaviour, i boot my pc, and instead of grub menu, i got a black screeen. I suppose it works well because i dont change the default option, then after 10 seconds, it boots ubuntu in graphical mode (as i wanted, instead of kernel messages in console) and i get into the login screen in graphical interface.

Some kind grub isnt displayed properly. Any ideas ?? I want my grub back again.

Boot message ( i repaired the boot with boot-repair, and i got this information):
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MdtkrKWWpV/

Edit requested by comment:

- No dual boot ( only ubuntu system)
- If i press ESc then grub appears but with black and white screen not default purple ubuntu theme. Also is a kind of simple menu ( ex: without memtest option).

Comment: Please edit your question and add if this is a dual boot computer? If there computer only has Ubuntu, grub should not show. If you press shift or esc (I forget which one) when there black screen shows, do you get the grub menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a computer with just Ubuntu installed (no other OS), GRUB elegantly hides its menu during the 10 sec timeout by default (unless you **hit escape** during the timeout), because in most cases, there's only one choice anyways and that way the user is less likely to be confused by the GRUB menu.

If you'd like to *always* see the GRUB menu, change the default:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

(replace `nano` with `gedit` if you'd like a GUI, or with `vi` if you can remember how to use that). Look for:

```
 GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

and change that into

```
 GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

Next, update the GRUB config in the boot area:

```
 sudo update-grub
```

You will now see the menu every time you boot. More info in the [manual pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Simple-configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks it helped me, but last question, how can i going back to original theme in grub boot menu ubuntu 20.04 ???

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'original theme'?

Comment: As i can remember in grub i had the same background as login screen ( or similar with purple color), so was also in 18.04 ... also appered menu options like memtest that doesnt appear now...thanks

Comment: Take a look at `GRUB_THEME` and GFX settings in the [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

Comment: Should you feel your (initial) question was answered, would you please click on 'anwered' so this issue is closed?

Comment: Well i have looked to the link of Grub manual, but i dont know where to get and which theme is the default in ubuntu 20.04. Also i have less options than before in the menu, like memtest....

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126160/how-can-i-add-the-memtest86-options-back-to-the-grub-menu) help you? I've seen in your boot-repair log that you are booting MBR (aka BIOS, **not** EFI). You _should_ be able to boot memtest86+. In (U)EFI mode, memtest no longer works.

Comment: Yes, the GRUB menu has changed from 18.04. I suggest you ask another question, like: "How do I get 18.04 style to 20.04 GRUB?"